# Create index error "could not read block 0"

Tags: postgresql

So I got a super weird problem here.  I spun up a new server to restore a backup (tried taking a new snapshot and restoring a backup few times since original server is doing well).

```
create index on companies ((linkedin_name(company url)));
```

this works on the original server (pgsql 14).  on the new server (pgsql 15) I get this error

```
could not execute query: ERROR:  could not read block 0 in file "base/16387/8646581": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
```

this is where it gets weird.  if I do this, it works fine

```
create table companies2 as select * from companies;
create index on companies2 ((linkedin_name(company url)));
```

this works just fine... THEN... and this is where it gets REALLY weird.

```
drop table companies;
alter table companies2 rename to companies;
```

this shows the index but if I try to reindex I now get the same error!!

... I don't even know where to begin to debug this.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.  The function referenced the table I wanted to create the index on and apparently that's a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that you are lying to the database. You declared the function `linkedin_name()` as `IMMUTABLE`, when clearly it isn't. If you use that function in an index definition, you will end up with data corruption, as evidenced by your problem.